# Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create 2 triggers that can add "default" values to the other tables. Everything was working fine with just one trigger (`addDefaultRole`), but when I've added the second one, everything broke.

Everything is handled through the **main 'users' table** when a new user tries to register on the website. This is the code from `register.php` script

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
      $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param_username, $param_password);

      $param_username = $username;
      $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      if($stmt->execute()) {
        header("location: login.php");
      } else {
        echo "<script> window.onload = alert('Something went wrong! Try again.') </script>";
      }
```

The 'users' table has 2 triggers now:

**addDefaultRole**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `addDefaultRole` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_role (user_role.userID, user_role.roleID) VALUES (NEW.id, 1);
END
```

**addDefaultIcon**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `addDefaultIcon` AFTER INSERT ON `users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_icon (user_icon.userID, user_icon.iconID) VALUES (NEW.id, 1);
END
```

The problem is when I try to execute the `INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)` statement through SQL, I get the error mentioned: `Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger` and I can't get my head around it, since every answer I found was telling me to use `NEW` (**which I am already using**) or switch the `AFTER INSERT` to `BEFORE INSERT` (**which I can't since I need the NEW.id when user registers**).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've never taken this approach. I use transactions in PHP.

Comment: @user3783243 Well, I've thought this is what triggers were created for, so I've tried using this method and it clearly did not pay off.